# How to link ad images with ad insights? (Facebook Ads Python SDK)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to connect ads insights with the ad image urls so that I can display the ads and their performance in a dashboard. Therefore, I need to merge the 'ad insights' dataset with the 'ad image' dataset. I know how to pull them separately, but don't know which column can be used as a key ID column to merge the two datasets. (Note that there are a lot more fields available through the API than the ones I used below.)

Get insights:

```
insights = account.get_insights(fields=[
    AdsInsights.Field.date_start,
    AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
    AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
    AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
    AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
    AdsInsights.Field.inline_post_engagement,
    AdsInsights.Field.video_10_sec_watched_actions,
    # AdsInsights.Field.canvas_avg_view_time,
], params={
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.ad,
    'breakdowns': 'publisher_platform',
    'time_range': {'since': str(datetime.date(2017,1,15)), 'until': str(datetime.date(2017,1,21))},
})
```

Ads insights output example:

```
<AdsInsights> {
    "ad_id": "6074251934453",
    "ad_name": "Post 185|Campaign|Video|:15 Video|Chloe Ombre Legging|Womens|11.11|Gap|Holiday|Marcom|GapFit|On-figure",
    "clicks": "80",
    "date_start": "2017-01-15",
    "date_stop": "2017-01-21",
    "impressions": "29898",
    "inline_post_engagement": "65",
    "publisher_platform": "instagram",
    "video_10_sec_watched_actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "video_view",
            "value": "2342"
        }
    ]
}
```

Get images:

```
images = account.get_ad_images(fields=[
    AdImage.Field.account_id,
    AdImage.Field.created_time,
    AdImage.Field.creatives,
    AdImage.Field.permalink_url,
], params = {
    'time_range': {'since': str(datetime.date(2017,1,15)), 'until': str(datetime.date(2017,1,21))}
})
```

Ad image output example:

```
<AdImage> {
    "account_id": "104181146376574",
    "created_time": "2017-03-08T10:45:57-0800",
    "creatives": [
        "6079059384653",
        "6079059384853",
        "6079059387253"
    ],
    "id": "104181146376574:d2d60f26e67d99e6869c9b8444a3b30c",
    "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/ads/image/?d=AQIY0GjCTF9UUMExzqq2QAI3hFKgmObAyivAwfb346WgnzAIiysmGLjU_msd1pJcVxcr4zawWXHsiRviQjrW50lqTXxq3to6CQIQFLptp9DZ9Kanqx0tmFqoIB1_37PLqjGo7cK1bt6G2YxaL29ihdge"
}
```

The 'ad_id' and the 'creatives' look similar but nothing matched after trying to merge them.

Anyone had previous experience dealing with this issue before? Any input/thought will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ad Images should be thought of as more like a 'library' of content you can use later, don't try to correlate Insights back to this, as there may be 0, 1, or more ads using a specific image, or ads not using images from this library

The data model for your purposes should probably be Ad Set -> Ad -> Ad Creative

The Ad Creative contains the details of what's being promoted, which is usually a Post on a page, and that post has an 'image' field

Comment: If you're tracking based on specific images you know were used on specific ads, you could also track that image->ad link in your own app

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the differences between ad images and ad creatives; I was confused by the different purposes of the two. It makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following way:

1. Get the insights like you already have `ad_id/insights`
2. Get the creative like `ad_id?fields=creative`
3. Then you can get the image url like `creative_id?fields=image_url`

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers above; you pointed me to the right direction. Here's my solution to my own question, which has been working great so far:

```
# get insights
insights = account.get_insights(fields=[
    AdsInsights.Field.date_start,
    AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
    AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
    AdsInsights.Field.impressions
], params={
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.ad,
    'time_range': {'since': str(datetime.date(2017, 3, 31)), 'until': str(datetime.date(2017, 3, 31))}
    'time_increment': 1
})

# get a list of ad ids
insights_ids = [insight['ad_id'] for insight in insights]

url_list = []
count = 0

for ad_id in insights_ids:
    ad = Ad(fbid=ad_id)
    # get creative by ad_id
    adcreatives = ad.get_ad_creatives(fields=[
        AdCreative.Field.thumbnail_url,
        AdCreative.Field.body
    ])
    count += 1
    print count
    url_dict = {'ad_id': ad_id,
                'thumbnail_url': adcreatives[0]['thumbnail_url']
                }
    url_list.append(url_dict)
    time.sleep(2)  # will likely hit rate limit when set to 1 sec
```

Hope this helps whoever encounters the same question!